# Derivative of $||\vec{x}||^2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, vectors

I know that $\nabla_x ||\vec{x}|| = \frac{\vec{x}}{||\vec{x}||}$, with ||.|| being the euclidean norm. However is the following calculation correct for the square of the norm:

$\nabla_x ||\vec{x}||^2 = 2||x||*\frac{\vec{x}}{||\vec{x}||} = 2*\vec{x}$ ... ?

Comment: Yes, it follows from the chain rule $\nabla{\psi\phi}=\phi\nabla\psi+\psi\nabla\phi$

Comment: stupid question maybe, but I thought that in general the chain rule can not be applied to matrix differentation. Take e.g. the differentiation of regression objective: $||Y-X\beta||^2$, where the derivative with regards to beta is not solely $2||Y-X\beta||*(-X)$

Comment: Here you have a gradient of the scalar field, and I've called a product rule - the chain rule, that is a mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, and probably the easiest way to see that is to actually write out the definition of the euclidean norm squared and take the gradient.
$$\nabla_\vec{x}\|\vec{x}\|^2=\nabla_\vec{x} (\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}^2) = \nabla_\vec{x} (\sum_i x_i^2)=\{2x_1,2x_2,\dots 2x_n\}=2\vec{x}$$
So it is exactly as you said.

I suggest for relatively simple matrix- or vector-argument functions to write out the function in summation notation if possible, then take derivatives. It can help a lot. If you really want to get into calculus with matrices, I recommend Jan Magnus' "Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics", which is available free online as a pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the tipps. In fact that is what I do at the moment, it prevents mistakes